# Explaining the conditional statement of Riemann Integral definition

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

A function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is said to be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if there exists a number $L\in\Bbb R$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta_{\varepsilon}>0$ such that if ***P*** is any tagged partition of $[a,b]$ with $\Vert$***P***$\rVert<\delta_{\varepsilon}$ then $|S(f;$***P***$)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Where $S(f;$***P***$)$ is the Riemann sum of f corresponding to ***P***.

I am not understanding the definition; I think the part
$|S(f;$***P***$)-L|<\varepsilon$ is to make sure the function value exists at the tagged value.

But what for the part $\lVert$***P***$\rVert<\delta_{\varepsilon}$, which is always should be true as there is always a value that is larger than the norm of any partitioned interval...

Comment: You probably mean $|S(f;\mathbf P) - L |<ε$.

Comment: @MartinR, you are right.

Comment: Yes there are values $\delta$ greater than the norm of any given partition, but when $\delta_\epsilon$ is chosen, you only know what $f, [a,b]$ and $\epsilon$ are. You do not have a partition yet. You have to choose a $\delta_\epsilon$, so that for **any** partition $\bf P$, with $\|\mathbf P\| < \delta_\epsilon, |S(f; \mathbf P) - L| < \epsilon$ will be true. You have to pick a $\delta$ that will work with all partitions with smaller norm, not pick a partition, and then pick a $\delta$.